# Tkinter grid question

Tags: tkinter

I have this code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):



        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()


        self.e = Entry(frame)
        self.e.grid(row=0, column=0)


        b = Button(frame, text='Search', command=self.well)
        b.grid(row=0, column=1)
def well(self):
    l0 = Label(Admin, text='first line')
    l0.grid(row=1)




    b0 = Button(Admin, text='F line S col')       

    b0.grid(row=1, column=1)
Admin = Tk()

app = App(Admin)
Admin.mainloop()
```

The ouput i get is THe Label and the Button on top of the Entry box. Does anyone know why this is? And how could i fix it to make it so that it is under the entry box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to tie the label and button to the frame you've created in **init**, not the global Admin object. Replace `frame = Frame(master)` with `self.frame = Frame(master)`, then in well(), change references of `Admin` to `self.frame`.